# Passing pointer to subroutine, compilation discrepancy between xlf and ifort compilers

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am having difficult understanding why a segment of Fortran code compiles without problems with an IBM compiler but raises a compile time error on the intel compiler. This segment is part of a larger code which is not written by me, but the people who wrote this primarily use IBM machines.

Th following function call raises the error:

```
call mapsort_qsortRC(map%s(n:m),map%row(n:m),map%col(n:m))
```

where the `map` type is a custom data type with many field, but the relevant ones are declared as:

```
 real   ,pointer :: s  (:)      ! the non-zero matrix elements
 integer,pointer :: row(:)      ! matrix row corresponding to each element
 integer,pointer :: col(:)      ! matrix col corresponding to each element
```

The subroutine `mapsort_qsortRC`  is declared as

```
recursive SUBROUTINE mapsort_qsortRC(S,row,col)

   implicit none

   !--- arguments ---
   real   (R8) ::   S(:)
   integer(IN) :: row(:),col(:)
```

The precision type `R8` is defined as

```
integer,parameter :: R8 = selected_real_kind(12) ! 8 byte real
```

The intel compiler raises the error "The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument." with regards to the variable `S` of the `map` datatype. I can see that we are passing a `real, pointer` to an argument that expects a `real` but i am not familiar with pointers in fortran. But more importantly how does one compiler handle it just fine, but not the other?

Comment: If, with each compiler, you do `kind(0.)` and `kind(0._R8)` what do you get?

Comment: That is, something like `print*, kind(0.), selected_real_kind(12); end`

Comment: @francescalus your comment prompted me to look at the compiler flags for the size of real. Turns out that the ibm compiler was being passed a ``-qrealsize=8`` flag. Passing ``-real-size 64`` to the intel compiler fixes the issue. Silly me!

Comment: Not silly at all.  I'm more a fan of recommending that people use kind specifiers consistently rather than relying on compiler flags.  Well demonstrated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't related to `pointer` and `not-pointer`.  When a pointer, such as `map%s` (a pointer component of a type), is referenced in a procedure to be associated with a dummy argument without the `pointer` attribute, it is the *target* of that pointer which is argument associated with the dummy.

Your real problem is to do with the *kind* of the argument.

The component `s`, although a pointer, is default real.  The dummy argument of the subroutine is a real, but a real of kind `R8`.  For some processors a default real has the same kind value as a real of kind `R8`.  For some it hasn't.  You are stuck between these two cases - either through design of the compiler, or through flags you've used.

For compiler flags, it's commonly the case that promoting default real to double, quadruple, etc., precision won't change the corresponding kinds of those variables given explicit kind values - even when those kind values are the same as that of a default real.

So, to make your code more portable, consider declaring the component `s` as `real(R8)`.

Comment: In the longer term, the same issue is present with the integer components/arguments.  Although this hasn't been a problem so far, it may be good practice to consistently provide kinds for those, too.